# Obtener valor de select con javascript by name

Tags: javascript

Buen dia, he tratado de obtener el valor seleccionado de un select mediante javascript por la propiedad name, pueden guiarme?, he visto muchos ejercicios donde se hace por id, pero lo deseo por name.

Tengo el siguiente codigo pero me funciona para obtener los valores por id del elemento:

```js
 var selectUser = document.getElementById('User'); var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Lo que deseo es obtener el valor mediante el name del elemento, lo estaba realizando de la siguiente manera, pero no me funciona:

```js
 var selectUser = document.getElementByName('User'); var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Comment: Lo estaba obteniendo por id de la siguiente manera: var selectUser = document.getElementById('User'); var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;  si me funciona de esa manera, pero si lo cambio por name de la siguiente manera no me funciona y esto es lo que requiero: var selectUser = document.getElementByName('User'); var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

Comment: Esta actualizada

Comment: Para empezar la función es incorrecta, colocaste `getElementByName()` cuando la función correcta es `getElementsByName()` y su uso es diferente al de `getElementById()`, te recomiendo leer la [documentación oficial](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp), pero te adelanto que lo que obtienes de esta función no es un elemento sino un vector de elementos.

Comment: ¿Qué es e? ¿Y que intentas obtener con el e.options[e.selectedIndex]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para seleccionar el elemento select por el nombre puedes utilizar:

```
document.querySelector("[name='user']");
```

A continuación un ejemplo:

```js
var selectUser = document.querySelector("[name='user']"); 
selectUser.addEventListener("change",(e)=>{
console.log(selectUser.options[selectUser.selectedIndex].value);
})
```

```html
<select name="user">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```